# understanding the definition of projective closure in Silverman

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I am reading Silverman's the Arithmetic of Elliptic curves. On page 9, he gave the following definition of projective closure of $V$:

> **Definition.** Let $V\subset \mathbb{A}^{n}$ be an affine algebraic set with ideal $I(V)$, and consider $V$ as a subset of $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ via 
>   $$V\subset \mathbb{A}^{n}\xrightarrow{\phi_{i}} \mathbb{P}^{n}.$$ 
>   The *projective closure of* $V$, denoted $\overline{V}$, is the projective algebraic set whose homogeneous ideal $I(\overline{V})$ is generated by
>   $$\{f^{*}(X):f\in I(V)\}.$$

In order for this definition to make sense, I must know the following result: there is a unique projective algebraic set $W$ such that $I(W)=(f^{*}(X):f\in I(V))$. But I don't know how to prove the result. Or do I misunderstand the definition?

Comment: What is a projective algebraic set for you?

Comment: There is a unique projective set $W$ that is the zero set of the given homogeneous ideal, call it $I^*$. It's not clear that $I(W)=I^*$, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Bernard $V$ is a projective algebraic set if $V=V_{I}$ for some homogeneous ideal $I$.

Comment: Well, what is the problem? To the ideal $I(V)$ you associate the *homogeneous* ideal $I^*$ generated by the homogeneised polynomials $f^*$ for all $f\in I(V)$, and this homogeneous ideal defines a projective algebraic set in $\mathbf P^n$.

Comment: @jgon If $I^{*},W$ are defined as you said, why does $I(W)=I^{*}$?

Comment: @Bernard If we define $\overline{V}$ to be $V_{I^{*}}$, then we must check to see it satisfies all the requirements from the definition. It is a projective algebraic set. But why do we have $I(V_{I^{*}})=I^{*}$?

Comment: That's because we have we have $\,\mathcal I(V(I))=I$ for the corresponding affine algebraic set, by de-homogeneisation  and re-homogenisation.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you! I think I understand now.